# How to fix: unable to get index of element in a set

Tags: c++, set

If I have a set of strings:

```
std::set<string> my_set;
```

And I want to find the index of an element in this,
I did:

```
auto it = std::find(my_set.begin(), my_set.end(), string_to_find);
auto index = std::distance(my_set.begin(), it);
for ( auto s : store){
    if(s.name == my_set[index]){  //line causing error
       s.item += 1;
       }
  }
```

where store is a vector of `class<Store>` which contains the string `name` as a field.
What am I doing wrong, how else does one get the index of an element of a set?

I currently get the error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’
```

Comment: This looks like [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want the "index"?

Comment: The way to dereference an iterator `it` isn't by trying to convert it into an index and invoking `operator[]`, it's by calling `*it`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) doesn't have `operator[]`.

You have already got an iterator, so you can use that to access an element.

```
auto it = std::find(my_set.begin(), my_set.end(), string_to_find);
if (it != my_set.end()){
    for (auto s : store){
        if(s.name == *it){
            s.item += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::set` does not implement the `operator[]` because it does not store elements contiguously and there is no way to access it directly through index.

Change

```
if(s.name == my_set[index]){
```

to

```
if(s.name == *it){
```

should work.